# Validating checkboxes

Tags: vb.net, checkbox

I'm a beginner at programming I have 3 CheckBoxes and 1 TextBox.
When CheckBox1 and CheckBox2 are checked then the text in the TextBox should be 1, otherwise it should be 0.

This is my code :

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged,
    CheckBox2.CheckedChanged

    If CheckBox1.Checked And CheckBox2.Checked Then
       TextBox1.Text = 1
    Else
       TextBox1.Text = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

This works except when I checked all three of them, the TextBox doesn't change to 0 and is still 1. How do I solve this? I tried to changing my code to

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged,
    CheckBox2.CheckedChanged

    If CheckBox1.Checked And CheckBox2.Checked Then
       TextBox1.Text = 1
    ElseIf CheckBox1.Checked And CheckBox2.Checked And Checkbox3.Checked Then
       TextBox1.Text = 0
    Else
       TextBox1.Text = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Is it possible to group all checkboxes in an array? Then I will count if more than 2 CheckBoxes are checked, and do something.

Comment: Try using Checkbox1.checked = True AND Checkbox2.checked = True

Comment: Turn on Option Strict - it will save you lots of grief (and simple SO questions).  `TextBox1.Text = 1` and the like is not valid

Comment: @GNMercado I tried, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Plutonix Yep, thanks in advance :)

Comment: @AAR If I would create this, I place the condition into a "click" event of a button in order to validate. Its quite simpler.

Comment: @GNMercado, what's the point of comparing one `Boolean` to another `Boolean` to get a third `Boolean` when you can just use the first `Boolean`?  `CheckBox1.Checked = True` evaluates to the exact same value as `CheckBox1.Checked` so what's the point of the comparison?

Comment: Not for nothing but this sort of "dilemma" is easily sorted out using the handy and powerful debugger built in to VS.  Set a breakpoint and watch the code execute.  Use to mouse to view variable contents.  You will learn a *great deal* about programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is your order.  In this case:

```
If CheckBox1.Checked And CheckBox2.Checked Then
   TextBox1.Text = 1
ElseIf CheckBox1.Checked And CheckBox2.Checked And Checkbox3.Checked Then
   TextBox1.Text = 0
Else
   TextBox1.Text = 0
End If
```

That second condition will never be tested because, for it to be `True`, the first condition will be `True` too and will have already matched.  You need to swap the first two conditions:

```
If CheckBox1.Checked And CheckBox2.Checked And Checkbox3.Checked Then
   TextBox1.Text = "0"
ElseIf CheckBox1.Checked And CheckBox2.Checked Then
   TextBox1.Text = "1"
Else
   TextBox1.Text = "0"
End If
```

You should be using `AndAlso` rather than `And` too.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to group all checkboxes in an array? Then I will count
>   if more than 2 CheckBoxes are checked, and do something.

Make **one** handler that fires for all three CheckBoxes by listing each one after the "Handles" keyword (scroll to the right to see the end of the first line):

```
Private Sub CheckBoxes_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged, CheckBox2.CheckedChanged, CheckBox3.CheckedChanged

End Sub
```

Now count up how many of the CheckBoxes are checked and act accordingly:

```
Private Sub CheckBoxes_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged, CheckBox2.CheckedChanged, CheckBox3.CheckedChanged
    Dim CheckCount As Integer
    Dim CheckBoxes() As CheckBox = {CheckBox1, CheckBox2, CheckBox3}
    For Each CB As CheckBox In CheckBoxes
        If CB.Checked Then
            CheckCount = CheckCount + 1
        End If
    Next
    TextBox1.Text = If(CheckCount >= 2, 1, 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP is rather unclear.  That code will do as asked in that last line but that last line contradicts what was asked earlier.